# onclick behaves oddly - refreshes page instead of displaying content

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, refresh

Here is my code, shortened for ease of access;

HTML

```
<a  onclick="showHideDiv('bio')" target='_self'>
  bio
  <div id="bio" class="shadowScreen" style="display: none;">
    <p class="showBio">
      Bio!
    </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var curDiv;

function showHideDiv(id){
  if (curDiv!==null){
    document.getElementById(curDiv).style.display="none";
  }
  document.getElementById(id).style.display="inline";
  curDiv=id;
}
```

CSS:

```
.shadowScreen{
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px;
}
.showBio{
  background-color: white;
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

When the 'a' element is clicked "showDiv(div)" is supposed to send a function call to JS which alters "display:none;" to "display:inline;". The HTML will now have the 'div' element which has the class "shadowScreen" which darkens the entire screen. I then have a 'p' element which centers a box on the screen and displays "bio!". But, it's not doing that, and I can't figure out why naht. I'm not the greatest with the Netbeans debugger, so I can't tell exactly what it's saying ;-;

If you need further clarification, just ask! I'll be more than happy to help you help me.

Comment: Why are you assiging id to curDiv at the end of the function

Comment: Irrespective to your code what art you trying to achieve?

Comment: Make sure you are calling showHideDiv(id) function instead of showDiv(id) on onclick event!

Comment: @divy3993 I am trying to achieve a picture that , onmousehover, displays two buttons; photo and bio. Both buttons shade the background while one of the buttons displays a photo and the other button a short bio

Comment: @Hurix If the user clicks on a bio while one is already open, the script first disables the old bio

Answer (score 1):

You should remove **target** and add "**#**" to href param as suggested.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showHideDiv('bio')">Bio</a>
```

Regarding your javascript code, try to initialise your **curDiv** variable with **null**.

```
var curDiv = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its redirecting because of the `a` tag.

You should replace:

```
<a  onclick="showHideDiv('bio')" target='_self'>
```

with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="showHideDiv('bio')" target='_self'>
```

Comment: It behaves differently, but still resets the page.

Comment: try removing `target`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll need to give your anchor tag a `href` attribute to make it valid. I'd suggest using the ID of the `div` you're toggling - `#bio` - or simply just `#`.

Next, you need to prevent the default action of your anchor tag in order to stop it executing the link you used in the `href` attribute. To do so, you need to add the following line to the end of your JavaScript function:

```
return false;
```